# Creating my own "clang-format" style that can be used across multiple projects with the "BasedOnStyle" setting

Tags: cmake, llvm, clang-format, project-structure

I have multiple projects that I want to share a similar .clang-format style, but I also want to be able to make minor tweaks between each project so they can be slightly different from one another if needed. Currently each project just has the same .clang-format file copied and pasted into its own repository, but it feels wrong because all of the style options are just duplicated from project to project and if I need to change one option I need to go across all projects and manually change it in all of them.

I would like to create my own style that can be used with the "BasedOnStyle" option (See [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more info). That way I can specify that I want all of these projects to be based on the same custom style that would be kept in a shared location, and then I could easily override any project specific options on a per-project basis.

As far as I can tell, there doesn't appear to be any way to create your own style and save it so other projects can be based on the same style. I feel like this is something a lot of users would need (for example if a company wanted to define their own master style that all projects should follow there doesn't appear to be a good way to do it).

Has anyone else run into this problem and found a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the llvm-dev email list and got a response. A feature request is in the works to do something *similar* to what I want, but not exactly the same. Either way, this should be suitable for my needs when it becomes available.

https://reviews.llvm.org/D93844